# Как вывести строку на консоль в Eclipse

Tags: java

Имеется метод nextLine(), позволяющий считывать целую последовательность символов, т.е. строку, а, значит, полученное через этот метод значение нужно сохранять в объекте класса String. В следующем примере создаётся два таких объекта, потом в них поочерёно записывается ввод пользователя, а далее на экран выводится одна строка, полученная объединением введённых последовательностей символов.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1, s2;
        s1 = sc.nextLine();
        s2 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s1 + s2);
    }
}
```

Я работаю в Eclipse и не могу никак вивести ето на консоль
Может версия java не подходит 
Помогите !!!

Comment: код работает нормально. вводите одну строку, нажимаете Enter, вторую строку, еnter - и смотрите на результат

Answer (score 2):

Видимо Вы не включили отображение консоли в Eclipse. Зажмите **Alt + Shift + Q** отпустите клавиши и нажмите на **C**. Код рабочий.